# How to mark a row in a group of rows in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I would like to mark a row from group of records based on some rules. I have a dataframe like below

```
id  price date
a   100   2016
a   200   2016
a   100   2016
b   100   2016
b   100   2015
```

My output dataframe should be

```
id  price date
a   200   2016
b   100   2016
```

In the given dataframe the rules are based on two columns.From the group of ids(a,b), first one based on the maximum price and second one based on recent date.My actual rules are more complicated and it involve lot of other columns too.

What is best approach for solving problem like this. Need to pick a row from a group of rows based on some rules.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by "marking a row". Also something else, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @eliasah "marking a row" means flagging the row from group of rows. In here 2nd row of (id a) and first row of (id b).I havn't made much progress on this, I tried by using collect_set  to get all the values and trying to apply the rules.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
val df = Seq(("a",100,2016), ("a",200,2016), ("a",100,2016), ("b",100,2016),("b",100,2015)).toDF("id", "price", "date")
df.show
val df1 = df.select($"id", struct($"price", $"date").alias("data")).groupBy($"id").agg(max("data").alias("data")).select($"id", $"data.price", $"data.date")
df1.show
```

You will get the output like below.

```
+---+-----+----+
| id|price|date|
+---+-----+----+
|  b|  100|2016|
|  a|  200|2016|
+---+-----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks @abaghel.My actual rules are bit complicated than max agg function. I am looking a for a solution, where I can specify custom rules.Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Another option is to register the Dataframe as temp table using df.createOrReplaceTempView("myTable") and then use SQL query on that table. You can also use UDF to handle your rule/logic.

Comment: Replace the max func with custom functions, I.e.UDF